# How to config. Linq DataContext (in Class Lib Proj) to use connection string in web.config of web application?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm looking for a solution on how to configure Linq DataContext in Class Library Project in order to use Connection String in web.config of web application. 
Your advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a solution to your problem, but you have to create app.config (or web.config I believe) in a startup project (the project which is executed for solution). Click on project, add new, general, application configuration file (in case of app.config).

Then you have to add some content. That's it.